# Is it possible to save the messages received by push notification (firebase) in async storage?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to list all messages already received via push notifications in a list in my app. I thought about saving them in asyn storage, but the function that runs in the background cannot perform the save action. Is it possible to do that? If yes, how can I do it?

The code I tried to implement:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import App from './App';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { name as appName } from './app.json';

/**
 * Background Received Push Notification Firebase
 */
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem('@myapp:notifications', JSON.stringify({name:'teste'}));
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rather recommend to save the messages you send in a firestore `collection` or RTD List for each user and for each user under his `uid`. That way you don't depend if device got it and if the app is in focus or not. It would allow for each user to read the received messages even when switching devices. That is how I do it every App that use FCM and needs to display the messages separately on UI for later review.